# Sort order list box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, arraylist, listbox

I have this code which I am trying to sort a list box Alphabetically.

However, when I try to sort more than one item it crashes the search.

The list box has a numeric value ID and a text item.

```
Sub sortListBoxItems(ByRef box As ListBox)
    'sorts listbox 
    Dim listarray As New ArrayList()
    Dim loopitem As Integer
    For loopitem = 0 To box.Items.Count - 1
        listarray.Add(box.Items(loopitem))
    Next

    listarray.Sort()
    box.Items.Clear()

    For loopitem = 0 To listarray.Count - 1
        box.Items.Add(listarray(loopitem))
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a smarter way of this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it crashes the search".  In what way does it crash?  Does it throw an exception or display an error?  If so, what is the message?  Do you have a stack trace?  If so, which line causes the problem?

Comment: The error is: Failed to compare two elements in the array.

On the line: listarray.Sort()

Comment: So, what are the types of the objects that are in the `ListBox`?

Comment: The list box contains an integer which is the Data Value Field and a string for Data Text Field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding two different types of objects to the list, and you are then trying to sort them using the default method, which does not handle comparing different types of objects with each other.  For instance:

```
Dim list As New ArrayList()
list.Add("Two")
list.Add(1)
list.Sort()  ' Throws an InvalidOperationException ("Failed to compare two elements in the array.")
```

However, you can implement your own `IComparer` class, which will handle multiple types, for instance:

```
Public Class MyComparer
    Implements IComparer

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Return x.ToString().CompareTo(y.ToString())
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, you can sort the list, like this:

```
Dim list As New ArrayList()
list.Add("Two")
list.Add(1)
list.Sort(New MyComparer())  ' Works!
```

Answer (score 2):

The ListBox can be automatically sorted.
Use the Sorted property at design time: `Sorted=True'`

Comment: sorry, I am moving an item between two list boxes so this will not work.